# VBA - Set the correct Workbook taken from a Collection

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA here.

I'm trying to recover the reference of a Excel Workbook from a Collection and SOMETIMES I end with the error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Using the function "apriData()" I should have as a result a collection where:

**coll[1]** = reference to the WB opened from an excel file;
**coll[2]** = reference to the appExcell.

```
Function apriData() As Collection
Dim appExcel As Application
Dim coll As Collection
Set coll = New Collection
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

'create new excel application object
Set appExcel = New Application
'set the applications visible property to false
appExcel.Visible = False
'open the workbook with data
On Error GoTo Error1
Set wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("PATH OF THE EXCEL FILE TO SAVE THE WB - CENSORED")
On Error GoTo Error2
MsgBox ("DATA aperto")
coll.Add wb
coll.Add appExcel
Set apriData = coll
Exit Function
Error1:
        'close the application
        appExcel.Quit
        Exit Function
Error2:
       'close the workbooks
        wb.Close
        'close the application
        appExcel.Quit
        Exit Function
End Function
```

This function is used in my formatta() method to save the collection retrived from the apriData() and use the selected WB.
Here it's the code:
Sub formatta()

```
Dim collectionData As Collection
Set collectionData = New Collection
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim app As Application
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim target As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
sheetCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
For i = 1 To sheetCount
    If Sheets(i).Name = "CE" Then
        Sheets(i).Cells.Clear
    End If
Next i
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(2)
ws.Name = "CE"
Set target = ws.Range("A1")
Set collectionData = apriData
Set wbData = collectionData(1)
Set app = collectionData(2)
creaGriglia wbData
popolaGriglia wbData
'close the workbooks
wbData.Close
'close the application
app.Quit
End Sub
```

I think the problem could be the "Set collectionData = apriData" not referencing the correct WB value.

Thank you for every support.

Comment: Side note. Don't add an application instance to the collection. You can always get that from `.Application` called on a workbook.

Comment: Noted thank you! Any other advise to pass a Workbook from a collection to another without ending with an error?

Comment: I'd skip the `Collection` entirely and have the function just return a `Workbook`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new on VBA and can't follow you. I want to open a WB in back ground, go to selected sheet and start adding/multiplying/etc.. the data in that selected sheet and copy the result into another WB. Is it even possibile?

Comment: Yes that is very possible.

Comment: Still looking for some hints on how to start opening the corretct WB, returning another WB, and create an object referencing the proper sheet to start doing some simple math with........